# how to use the value of an anchor form

Tags: codeigniter

View:

```
<?php 
foreach ($query as $row){ 
    echo  '<tr><td>
           <label class="checkbox">' .
           form_checkbox('delete[]',$row['link']) .
           form_anchor('site/see_art',$row['link']) . 
           $row['title'] . "</a></td>
           <td> " . substr($row['pub_date'], 5, 12) . "</label></td></tr>"; 
} ?>
```

controller:

```
function see_art()
{       
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $this->membership_model->see_art();
}
```

model:

```
function see_art()
{       
    $this->db->where(array('title' => !!THE VALUE OF THE ANCHOR));
    $q = $this->db->get('feeds');}
    print_r($q->result());
}
```

In my view i have displayed some titles. I want to do something like that: when click on the title use the function controller and display me the row from my database where title = VALUE of the anchor. I don't know how to to that and how to use the value of anchor when click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have only a ways of doing it, without reload the page: **AJAX**

You have to program with javascript (I recommend you jQuery for doing the request) an event that allows you send the request to the server of the title.

In your don't know how to use it, check http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

You'll do the request to a method in your controller and see the answer there.

In your controller, you'll have something like

```
public function ajax_petition() {
     $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
     $this->load->model('membership_model');
     $title = $this->membership_model->get_title( $slug );

     return $title;
}
```

And you'll have to program your model to return the title only:

```
public function get_title( $slug ) {
    $object = $this->db->select('title')
    ->from('feeds')
    ->where('slug', $slug) 
    ->limit(1)
    ->get()

    return ($object->num_rows > 1) ? $object->row()->title : '';
}
```

I'm sorry, your question is very generic, but according to what you ask for, you have to use what I wrote you above

Other thing, not really related but important: NEVER print_r or echo in a Model. Model is only to retrieve data, controller only to get input data and call the models, and views only to show the data the controller send to them. Otherwise, you're killing the MVC, ;D

Your function above should be something like:

Controller:

```
function see_art()
{   
    // Get the input data from user
    $title =  $this->input->post('title');

    // Retrieve the data from the model
    $this->load->model('membership_model');        
    $data['feeds'] = $this->membership_model->see_art( $title );

    // Send them to the view
    $this->load->view('path_to_your_view', $data);
}
```

View

```
<?php // This will print all the feeds sent from the controller
foreach ($feeds as $feed){ 
    echo  '<tr><td>
           <label class="checkbox">' .
           form_checkbox('delete[]', $feed->link ) .
           form_anchor('site/see_art', $feed->link ) . 
           $feed->title . "</a></td>
           <td> " . substr($feed->pub_date, 5, 12) . "</label></td></tr>"; 
} ?>
```

Model:

```
// This will give you back all the feeds with the title sent
function see_art( $title )
{       
    $this->db->where( array('title' => $title ) );
    $q = $this->db->get('feeds');}
    return $q->result();
}
```

More things: when retrieving data from DDBB, use "select" and specify exactly the data you want, the performance of your application will be increased.

Last thing, maybe the controller, model and view are not accurate for what you want, but I only want to express the idea of how to do it.

Comment: thanks for the answer Chococroc. I don't know AJAX but i will look on it. What i want to do is to click on a title and display me all the row of DB that contains the title i've clicked

Comment: i've read on google about using anchor tags as a submit forms and i believe it can be done with that